# Axios GET request in React

Tags: reactjs, axios, shopify

I am trying to perform a GET request from the shopify API, but I don't know how to place credenrials in the reuqest body, using CURL it looks like this: `https://API_KEY:PASSWORD@myShop.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json`

But when I try to do the same with axios i'm getting  `xhr.js:173 GET http://localhost:3000/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)`
`index.js:1452 Error: Request failed with status code 404`, this is my code:

```
axios
  .get( { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" },
    "https://myShop.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json",

    {
      headers: {
        API_KEY: "key",
        PASSWORD: "password"
      }
    }
  )

  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    this.setState(response);
  })
```

I also tried to include the API_KEY and PASSWORD directly in the link, like in the CURL link, but this is not accepted by the browser as the keys would be exposed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: for start url should be the first argument of axios.get and options the second.

Comment: If i move it in second position i'm getting this error: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://myShop.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`, I already tried before this, but thanks!

Comment: Please understand that adding the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` will not prevent the CORS policy error. CORS has to be enabled on the receiving server.

Comment: You may want to check this about cors.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS and set your response headers accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a CORS error, you are doing things completely wrong. It means you are exposing your API credentials to the universe, which is probably something you do not want to do.

Comment: Yes, after some reading I understood this point, so I probably need to change strategy. What will be a better strategy?

Comment: Build an App, and then hook up an App Proxy. You can then securely make calls to the API and there are zero CORS problems.